# How to update pull request after master has changed

Tags: git, github

I have a master branch and 2 side branches. branch1 has its own commits and the commits from branch2 but branch2 does not have commits from branch1. I merged PR from branch2 into master. Somehow the PR from branch1 to master still shows branch2 commits as being part of the diff. If I just compare branch1 with master i dont see those commits. How do I update the PR to show the same thing that the diff does?

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes run into something similar to this on GitHub but when I do a

`git diff branch_1..branch_2`

on the branches in question, the changes that I know are already on the branch in question are not highlighted as diffs.  I don't know why the issue happens, but sometimes when I close the PR and open another one, it acts as expected.

Without knowing the timeline of changes on both of your branches, it's hard to tell if there is something wrong with your local git history or if it is a Github issue.

Comment: it's definitely a github issue :( all the diffs display correctly. if i close the PR and reopen it it displays correctly but I don't want to keep doing that. It looks like instead of doing a diff from branch master and my branch it is doing a diff from sha1 in master and my branch on the PR.

Comment: @bia.migueis Yea, good to see that your work is preserved and the future PRs are correct.  My team runs into something similar like once every 3 weeks.  If my answer was any help at all, can you up vote it- trying to be able to do more with this community.  Thanks!